# Single Line Print Statement based on condition (Blender Python)

Tags: python, blender

I'm trying to set up a condition to print different results when the condition is false. I am able to do this, but the results are formatted wrong.
Here are example of the statements I've tried

```
for mesh in objects:
 if mesh.type=="MESH" and mesh.users>0:
  if not mesh.modifiers:
      print (mesh.name, mesh.parent.name) if mesh.parent else (mesh.name, "no Parent")

01M_M-スカート_3_1 rigidbodies
01N_M-スカート_4_1 rigidbodies
('Cube', 'no Parent')
('smd_bone_vis', 'no Parent')
```

False result has Brackets and single quotes

```
for mesh in objects:
 if mesh.type=="MESH" and mesh.users>0:
  if not mesh.modifiers:
      print (mesh.name, mesh.parent.name if mesh.parent else mesh.name, "no Parent")

01M_M-スカート_3_1 rigidbodies no Parent
01N_M-スカート_4_1 rigidbodies no Parent
Cube Cube no Parent
smd_bone_vis smd_bone_vis no Parent
```

True results have both condition prints

```
for mesh in objects:
 if mesh.type=="MESH" and mesh.users>0:
  if not mesh.modifiers:
      print( mesh.name, mesh.parent if mesh.parent) else mesh.name, "no Parent"
  File "<blender_console>", line 4
    print( mesh.name, mesh.parent.name if mesh.parent) else mesh.name, "no Parent"

                                                     ^
```

Produces SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
for mesh in objects:
 if mesh.type=="MESH" and mesh.users>0:
  if not mesh.modifiers:
      print( mesh.name, mesh.parent.name) if mesh.parent else mesh.name, "no Parent"

01M_M-スカート_3_1 rigidbodies
(None, 'no Parent')
01N_M-スカート_4_1 rigidbodies
(None, 'no Parent')
('Cube', 'no Parent')
('smd_bone_vis', 'no Parent')
```

Produces, Well as you can see...

This is the result I expect if it runs correctly

```
01M_M-スカート_3_1 rigidbodies
01N_M-スカート_4_1 rigidbodies
Cube no Parent
smd_bone_vis no Parent
```

What am I doing wrong here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you should use is

```
for mesh in objects:
 if mesh.type=="MESH" and mesh.users>0:
  if not mesh.modifiers:
      print (mesh.name, mesh.parent.name) if mesh.parent else print(mesh.name, "no Parent")
```

This should give you your desired results.

Comment: Same thing with list comprehension:
for x in [x_ for x_ in objects if mesh.type == 'MESH' and mesh.users > 0]:
    print(...)

Comment: Thanks Roki, different question though, do you have some sort of "For Dummies" link to documentation where I can learn these type of statements. My code is full of FOR, WHILE and IF, ELIF, ELSE  statements that can probably be reduced to single line statements.